# NodeJS role based access control with client support

Tags: node.js, roles, rights

does any multi-client role based right libs exist for node?

I'm recently developing a nodejs application which requires a more sophisticated role based access control which supports multiple clients/mandates within the software. Different rights will be assigned to roles.

So basically the structure should be similar to:

```
User 1---n acl 1---n roles 1---n role_rights 1---n rights
            1---n clients
```

A user can have multiple roles for one or several partners. A role is specified for a partner. This means a user gets several rights for a partner.

I'd expect the library to

- authenticate,
- authorise
- supply middle layer for express to provide context
- support for mysql
- clients
- acl
- role
- rights
- support for modern spa eg angular 2

Comment: Lots of things to achieve with a module. If you care about "single responsibility principle" try https://github.com/onury/accesscontrol